# Adding click event to Window or document buggy in IE

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events, javascript-framework

Using the prevel framework to add a event is done like below
`pl(window).bind("eventname",handlerFunction);`

So I did this

```
pl(window).bind("click", function (ev) {
    if (ev.which == 1) {
        alert("Clicked");
    }
});
```

On clicking the document or window I was able to alert the string, but heck IE8 does not do the same. Is the Library broken or am I wrong with respect to IE. Prevel Javascript framework can be found here https://github.com/chernikovalexey/Prevel here is the code that should get you working http://jsfiddle.net/pKhHJ/

Comment: Doesn't look like a very good library, it uses browser sniffing where some very simple feature tests would be much better. Perhaps it is mis-sniffing IE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code "ev.which" is specific to firefox. For IE you have to use the code as "ev.keyCode". Try the code as shown below

```
pl(window).bind("click", function (ev) {
    if(!ev)
        ev = window.event;
  var kCode = ev.which || ev.keyCode;
    if (kCode == 1) {
        alert("Clicked");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: *"ev.which" is specific to firefox ...* - you do realize this is 2011 and there are more than 2 major browsers, don't you?  `which` is W3C standard, not *"specific to [F]irefox"*.  All the edge major browser versions (including IE 9) support it.  You might want to brush up on your DOM a little ;-)

Comment: @AmGates you ROCK, btw i have edited the code. left click is event code = 0 on ie but 1 on FF and others. God why should ie be this way

Answer (score 1):

It's [fixed already](https://github.com/chernikovalexey/Prevel/issues/1), as I see.